# Adding a png image to a java applet

Tags: java, image, applet, png

I am very new to Java, I want to add a PNG image to my applet. From some reason when I add this image I receive the following error:

Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.createBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.setPixels(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder.setPixels(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.sendPixels(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)

When I try adding a jpeg image it works fine. How do I work around this?

Comment: There is also similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045279/how-can-i-display-a-bitmap-image-in-a-java-applet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your PNG image? Judging by the stack trace you have given me, it appears that you run out of heap space when you try to create a `BufferedImage` from the image you load. You could try resizing the image to a smaller size.

You could first try increasing the heap size, to see if that solves the problem - see the [java_arguments](https://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/) parameter to an applet, though that won't be a permanent solution (no-one likes a memory hogging applet). You should also run your application through a profiler and see what is consuming most of the memory. An `OutOfMemoryError` could mean a memory leak somewhere. It could even be outside of your image-loading class, as the heap could have already been overfilled when trying to load an image, and the image loading causing it to fill up. Try to use the profiler in the [visualvm](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) as it will tell you the biggest consumers.

Hope it helps :)

`-- Flaviu Cipcigan`